# How to maintain collections of heterogeneous types that depend on each's concrete implementation?

Tags: java, generics, types

I'm trying to find a way to maintain heterogeneous types in multiple collections despite Java's type erasure.

Specifically, if I have a few interfaces

```
public interface Fuel {};

public interface Engine<T extends Fuel> {
  public void burn(T fuel);
}
```

I would like to be able to keep a collection of Fuels and a collection of Engines together. Such that I can call each engine's burn on the correct fuel type.

```
class PowerPlant {

  List<Engine<?>> engines;
  List<Fuel> fuels;

  public void run() {
    fuels.stream().forEach(fuel -> {
        engines
          .filter(/* Not where I need help. */)
          .burn(fuel); // This cast is my problem
    });
  }
}
```

The above fails with a fun type mismatch

```
The method burn(capture#24-of ?) in the type Engine<capture#24-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Fuel<capture#25-of ?>)
```

Is there no way to restore the types for the compiler to be happy?

(That's the end of my question, everything below is just different things I've tried.)

---

What I've found to actually compile far as the least-worst option is to have a meta container.

```
public class FuelEngine<T extends Fuel, S extends Engine<T>> {
  public T fuel;
  public S engine;

  public void burn() {
    engine.burn(fuel);
  }
}
```

Which I can then build into my `PowerPlant`

```
public class PowerPlant {
  List<FuelEngine<?, ?>> fuelEngines;

  public void run() {
    fuelEngines.stream().forEach(FuelEngine::burn);
  }
}
```

But I have a lot more methods than just burn (Eg `burnFast`, `burnSlow`, `mixFuel`, etc), and don't really want to have to copy paste a bunch of "dummy" methods for each new one that gets introduced inside `Engine`.

---

Things I've tried that failed or equally didn't compile or were worse (IMO).

1. Casting "dynamically"

```
public interface Engine<T extends Fuel> {
  public void burn(T fuel);
  public Class<T> getFuelType();
}
```

And then

```
public class PowerPlant {
  List<FuelEngine<?, ?>> fuelEngines;

  public void run() {
    fuelEngines.stream().forEach(fuelEngine -> {
      Engine<?> engine = fuelEngine.getEngine();
      engine.burn(engine.getFuelType().cast(fuelEngine.getFuel()));
    });
  } 
}
```

Gives the error

```
The method burn(capture#19-of ?) in the type Engine<capture#19-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#20-of ?)
```

2. Having a typed method

```
public PowerPlant {
  List<FuelEngine<?, ?>> fuelEngines;

  public void run() {
    fuelEngines.stream().forEach(fuelEngine -> burn(fuelEngine.getFuel(), fuelEngine.getEngine());
  }

  public <T extends Fuel, S extends Engine<T>> void burn(T fuel, S engine) {
    engine.burn(fuel);
  }
}
```

Gives the error

```
The method burn(T, S) in the type PowerPlant is not applicable for the arguments (capture#26-of ?, capture#28-of ?)
```

3. Custom heterogeneous typesafe container

```
class FuelContainer {
  Map<Class<?>, List<? extends Fuel>> fuelByType;

  public <T extends Fuel> List<T> getFuels(Class<T> type) {
    return fuelByType.get(type).stream().map(type::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

With `PowerPlant` implementation

```
public class PowerPlant {
  public List<Engine<?>> engines;
  public FuelContainer fuelContainer;

  public void run() {
    engines.stream().forEach(engine -> {
      fuelContainer.getFuels(engine.getFuelType()).stream().forEach(engine::burn);
    });
  }
}
```

Gives two errors!

```
The method forEach(Consumer<? super capture#33-of ?>) in the type Iterable<capture#33-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (engine::burn)
The type Engine<capture#34-of ?> does not define burn(capture#33-of ?) that is applicable here
```

4. Having `Engine` take in `Object` and do its own cast.

```
public interface Engine {
  public void burn(Object fuel); 
}
```

But that's just...ugly, and I lose type safety from my compiler.

5. Having a bunch of typed lists

```
public class PowerPlant {
  List<ElectricEngine> electricEngines;
  List<GasEngine> gasEngines;
  
  List<Electricity> electricies;
  List<GasFuel> gasFuels;
}
```

But that doesn't scale when I will have ~30 different engines and fuels.

Comment: Not possible, precisely because of type erasure. You can't distinguish between `Engine<Gas>` and `Engine<Electricity>` at runtime. But at compile time, you don't know what types are in the list, because the code hasn't been run. I would use a enum field to indicate the supported fuel.

Comment: Do you mean make `Fuel` an enum instead of an interface? Unfortunately that won't work directly, as each fuel has some information and stats that are unique (eg electricity has amperage/voltage, gas has octane, etc). But I do think you're right in that I need to do one of two things. Either remove heterogeneity of one of my collections, or add additional information to one of my collections that can be used in place of types. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: No, I mean _add_ a `FuelType` enum that has a case for each of the `Fuel` implementations there is, and add a `FuelType supportedFuel;` field in engine.

Comment: Oh! And then have a switch-case that hardcodes casts based on the `FuelType`?

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot raw types were a thing!

I'm already verifying the correct `Fuel` is being sent to the correct `Engine` with my filters. Using a raw type on the engines list results in only a warning (instead of an error) being emitted by the compiler. Those can be ignored, and now everything works exactly like I wanted!

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "java:S3740", "unchecked" })
class PowerPlant {

  List<Engine> engines; // Warning raw type
  List<Fuel> fuels;

  public void run() {
    fuels.stream().forEach(fuel -> {
        engines
          .filter(/* snip */)
          .burn(fuel); // Warning type safety
    });
  }
}
```

Whats a few @SuppressWarnings between friends?